# Use xml2js in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, xml2js

Is there an example of how to include xml2js in the browser page?

Per xml2js https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/215:

> "with the recent changes, xml2js should be working fine in the
>   browser.

A simple include does not seem to work :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/xml2js.js"></script>`

as it generates the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Is it a matter of running browserify to create a single file to include?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically `browserify`ing it should work as discussed at https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/277 (**"pietersv commented on Nov 2, 2017"**).

Quoting that:

Add the following two scripts to package.json and run them after running npm test:

```
"browserify": "browserify ./xml2js.js  -s xml2js -o ./xml2js.js",
"minify": "cat ./xml2js.js  | uglifyjs > ./xml2js.min.js"
```

in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/xml2js.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</note>'
    var obj = xml2js.parseString(xml, function(err, res) { ... })
</script>
```

However as at today (30.7.18) that is not working with the current version (0.4.19) as stated in the follow-up comment (by me!).

Instead I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js and browserfied it (in `package.json` is:

```
"buildxml2js": "./node_modules/.bin/browserify ./node_modules/xml-js/dist/xml-js.js -o ./public/lib/xml-js.js")
```

and it works a charm.  After building it as `./public/lib/xml-js.js` dir add this to the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/xml-js.js"></script>
```

And then call with:

```
xml2json(the_xml)
```

and

```
json2xml(the_json)
```

Sorry this doesn't actually solve your specific question, however it provides a viable work-around.